# Using A/C adapters with different current ratings

Tags: power-supply

Can I use an adapter AC/DC (Output 12V 500mA) instead of another A/C adapter (Output 12V 250mA) ?
If not What I will do to use the first one as the only adapter at my level

Comment: Yes. It is fine.

Answer (score 0):

It is a common misconception that a power supply's rated current is what it supplies at all times. What it actually means is that it will supply UP TO that current. So, if you've only got only half the load connected, it will be supplying around 250mA. You are quite safe to use your 500mA supply and you will be running at half it's possible maximum capacity.